# httmock not intercepting requests.send() when running tox

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I'm using httmock from PyPI (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/httmock/) to catch REST requests and mock them. I'll use it like this in my unit test code:

```
with httmock.HTTMock(my_request.token, my_request.put):
    payload = {'host-name': 'TestHost'}
    content = client.put_request('global/host-name',
                                  payload=payload)
```

The client class will, as part of the put_request() see that there is not authentication token and will first to a POST request with user and password to get the token, and then do the PUT request. There are asserts to check the results of the process.

I have a large set of tests, and when I run them using tox, these tests work just fine. However, if I run the full tox suite of tests, I have about 30 tests that fail. They all fail doing the authentication post.

I added debug into a copy of the httmock.py file and in the client code. What I see is that, at the **enter**() for it takes the requests.Session.send and saves it, replacing with a function to intercept, as expected. But, I never see the _fake_send() called in these failing cases (no log messages seen). As a result, it doesn't have any content returned (not token) and the test fails.

Here some annotated logging I did:

```
1 DEBUG [drivers.httmock] Have 2 handlers
2 DEBUG [drivers.httmock] Enter requests.sessions
3 DEBUG [client] Authenticating with 'localhost'
4 DEBUG [client] POST: Request for .../api/v1/auth/...
5 DEBUG [client] >>> module drivers.httmock
6 DEBUG [client] POST Took 0.00 seconds to process
7 DEBUG [client] POST: Completed [401]
8 ERROR [client] Failed authentication with localhost [401]
```

[1] shows that the with clause registered the two handlers. [2] is at dunder enter for the context manager and requests.Session.send is pointing to the normal module/function. [4] is the client just before calling requests.request(). [5] Shows that requests.Session.send has been swapped to the httmock. I was expecting to see logs at [6] for httmock trying the handlers, but instead I see the client message showing the call is done.

I looked at requests library and request() creates a session and calls session.Session.send() as expected.

I'm not positive, but I think with the full suite run, tox will run tests in parallel.

Anyone have an ideas as to what I maybe doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Found that httmock, swaps out session.send() with a fake method, which tries the various handlers defined for the context manager.

My code was calling requests.request(), which creates a new session, calls session.request(), which calls session.send(), and the mock was not intercepting the send() call.

My **guess** is this is because requests starts a new session for each call, if using the requests.* API. Found that my production code could create a requests Session and then use that same session for each call (and use the session's request() method instead of the requests.request() method).

Once done, this now works on a full tox run, which, BTW uses multiple threads to run the test methods (threading at the method level).